# watcher in vuejs not working for props value

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am working on vue app. The issue I am facing here is that I want to run a method if props has  value and in my case manager value. So I am trying something like this but the debugger is not called in the watcher. Please help me find where I am going wrong.

```
<script>
  export default {
    props: ['manager'],
    watch: {
      manager: function (value) {
        debugger
        if(value) {
          this.validationManager();
        }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      validationManager(){
        console.log("Hello")
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65197837/8172857

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to listen for 'props' changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44584292/how-to-listen-for-props-changes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can definetely watch the props, please try this:

```
watch: {
  manager: {
    // the callback will be called immediately after the start of the observation
    immediate: true, 
    handler (val, oldVal) {
      //do your stuff here
      this.validationManager();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forget the `deep` attribute for watcher

```js
    watch: {
      manager: {
        handler(value){
          if(value) {
            this.validationManager();
          }
        },
        immediate: true,
        deep: true,
      }
    }
```

Comment: If the prop is not a boolean, ```deep: true``` is needed to detect changes.
Also, you can try 'forcing' it with  `if (val !=== oldVal)` inside of
`handler (val, oldVal) { //do your stuff here
   this.validationManager();
 }` following @Stefanos_Apk's answer. @Ntx answer should work.