# watch on store mutations even for same values

Tags: vuex, vuejs3

I use this code to watch mutations, but the CB triggers only if *old* and *new* Values would **NOT** be equal,

```
VX.store.watch(
    getters => getters.focusedOn,
    ( value, oldValue ) => console.log( oldValue, value )
);
```

I get results like:

```
1 0
```

but I'm looking even for results like:

```
1 1
```

How can I get them? (even without using watch)

p.s. and I Don't like to convert my simple "focusedOn" to an object or so.

p.s. The createLogger reports all kind of mutations, so it made me thinking that there should be a way to get all of them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to watch prop even if it does not change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65197803/how-to-watch-prop-even-if-it-does-not-change)

Comment: thanks for suggestion, but I'm afraid Not (the link suggests to convert simple prop to an object or so). I am wondering why I can get the log of all mutations(via createLogger), but I can NOT get all mutations by watch?

Comment: watch runs only when the old/new values are different

Comment: Do u mean that providing old-new values in second watch parameters is useless when they are same?  and there is no way to get all the possible mutation by watch??
so how can I get all mutations? like what  createLogger does?

Comment: A watch is for changes to state, caused by mutations.  You're not asking about variable changes, rather the mutation events-- whether or not they change anything.  A logger would just track the mutations at the time they're called.